# Microsoft Graph get user photos

Tags: vba, microsoft-graph-api

I try to download the profile picture from some users in my organization. I'm getting the access_token, but in the next step  get the error message:

> The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be
>   understood.

My app has in my point of view all required [permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/profilephoto-get?view=graph-rest-1.0#permissions):
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBcAd.png)

Here is my used code:

```
Sub Test_GetToken()
    Dim xml As New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim url As String
    Dim Json As Object

    url = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenant_id/oauth2/v2.0/token"

    xml.Open "POST", url, False
    xml.setRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xml.Send ("client_id=1234678&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&client_secret=12345678&grant_type=client_credentials")

    Set Json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(xml.responseText)

    access_token = Json("access_token")
    token_type = Json("token_type")
    expires_in = Json("expires_in")
    ext_expires_in = Json("ext_expires_in")


    ' trying to get the photo
    url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user1@OUTLOOK.DE/photo/$value"

    xml.Open "GET", url, False
    xml.setRequestHeader "application", "x-www-form-urlencoded"
    xml.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
    xml.setRequestHeader "Authorization", token_type & " " & access_token

    xml.Send ("")

    'Debug.Print token_type & " " & access_token
    'Debug.Print xml.getAllResponseHeaders
    Debug.Print xml.responseText

    Set xml = Nothing
End Sub
```

Does anybody has an ideas where the mistake is?

Answer (score 3):

There are several things wrong here:

1. There isn't an `application` header in HTTP
2. `x-www-form-urlencoded` is an incomplete `Content-Type` (it should be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded).
3. Your `Content-Type` should be `application/json`
4. You cannot use the Client Credentials OAuth grant to access a Microsoft Account (i.e. a personal `@Outlook` address). Client Credentials can only access data from users within your tenant. In order to access personal account data, you need to have the user authenticate using either the Authorization Code or Implicit OAuth grants.

Comment: If I remove application in the header than x-www-form-urlencoded will be also removed. Is #2 than still necessary?

Comment: The mail adress in #4 was just an example. All desired are in my tenant. How can I get the Authorization Code or the Implicit OAuth grants (from the tenant administrators?)

Comment: If they're in your tenant, you can use Client Credentials. You should only be setting the `Content-Type` to `x-www-form-urlencoded` when fetching the token. You should be setting `Content-Type` as `application/json` when fetching the photo (you likely could skip it entirely since you're not posting any content anyway)

Comment: Ok thank, I will try it tomorrow. Do I need the permisson of my administrator of the tenant or can I get them e.g. with a logged-in user without permisson of the administrator?

Comment: You need Admin Consent to request `User.Read.All` with Client Credentials. If you're authenticating a user, then you _can_ fetch a photo using the `User.ReadBasic.All` delegated scope and avoid the consent issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got Admin Consent and now it works. thanks to Marc for improving my code and getting the solution.